# Array values change outside of loop - Java

Tags: java

I have a *2D* *ArrayList* as:

```
private ArrayList<double[]> allNeuronsParams = new ArrayList<double[]>();
```

I am trying to assign values to it inside a loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < getTotalNeuronNum(); i++) {

        allNeuronsParams.add(defaultParamCase1);        //this is fine

        setNeuronParam(i, 0, (double)NMassociatedNum);  //this is fine

        setNeuronParam(i, 1,extractedNeuronTypes[i]);   //this is the problem
    }
```

The problem is with my last assignment inside the loop:

```
        setNeuronParam(i, 1,extractedNeuronTypes[i]);
```

This line assigns values from `extractedNeuronTypes` array to the second index of each row of `allNeuronsParams` 2-D ArrayList via `setNeuronParam(row, index, value)` function.

When I print values inside the loop, everything is correct. But when I put a print statement after the loop, the values are not correct anymore.

The values that are printed are all 3, which is the default value for the `extractedNeuronTypes` array. Before my for loop I call another function, open a file and read new values into this array - not for all indices but for part of them the values change. For example values change from default values of {3, 3, 3, 3} to new values of {3, 2, 1, 3}.

But for some reason only the {3, 3, 3, 3} is accessed. Once again I print values inside the loop and the right numbers {3, 2, 1, 3} are assigned to the 2-D arrayList.

But here is what I get after the loop - bold numbers are wrong, everything else is fine:

> My parameters are: 1.0, **3.0**, -1.0, -2.345, 1.0, 1432345.1, -13456.0,
>   -1.4, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003
>
> My parameters are: 1.0, **3.0**, -1.0, -2.345, 1.0, 1432345.1, -13456.0,
>   -1.4, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003
>
> My parameters are: 1.0, **3.0**, -1.0, -2.345, 1.0, 1432345.1, -13456.0,
>   -1.4, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003
>
> My parameters are: 1.0, **3.0**, -1.0, -2.345, 1.0, 1432345.1, -13456.0,
>   -1.4, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003, 2.000003

Could anyone see what I am wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the main problem ? this is not the true way of asking question ...

Comment: Is it normal that all the other values are identical? Are you sure that the value is correctly read (did you print it out to make sure)?

Comment: Hi, I am sorry - first time asking a question! I am assigning values to a arraylist inside a loop and part of it changes outside of the loop

Comment: `allNeuronsParams.add(defaultParamCase1);` <- you add `defaultParamCase1` multiple times in your loop. So your List will contain the same Object multiple times. Are you sure that you didn't mean to add multiple **different** arrays?

Comment: Yes, everything is fine except 2nd values for each row

Comment: Only value 3 is the problem, everything else is the way it should be.

Comment: Well if you say that everthing is fine and you meant to add only one array multiple times then fine.... But the fact that in your comments you still talk about "2nd values for each row" kind of tells me it isn't. There is only one "2nd value" (singular) in your current code. You only have one "row" so to speak of.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like all your rows are referencing the same array (defaultParamCase1).

instead of doing

```
    allNeuronsParams.add(defaultParamCase1);
```

you should create a deep copy of defaultParamCase2, and add that copy to the Arraylist

Comment: Values of double array defaultParamCase1 are set inside another method and I set index 0 and 1 to -1 there - defaultParamCase1[0] = -1; defaultParamCase1[1] = -1; So shouldn't it print -1 instead of 3 if that is the case?

Comment: could you post the  setNeuronParam method?

Comment: This is the method:                                                                                `public void setNeuronParam(int neuronIndex, int paramIndex, double paramValue) {
  
  allNeuronsParams.get(neuronIndex)[paramIndex] = paramValue;
 }`

Answer (score 0):

OK - Thanks everybody for your help. I finally figured out what the problem was. Some of you actually mentioned this, though it took me some time to figure it out.

I wanted to add the same array multiple time to my arrayList; however, I was not aware that even in this case we need to create new space for each row of the arrayList - given that my arrayList is 2-D.

So at the beginning of my method I added the following line:

`allNeuronsParams.add(new double[getNumOfParams(defaulParamFilePath)+2]);`

Prior to this I was using one array and I was adding that one array multiple times so all references were pointing to the same array and only values from the last iterations were being saved and printed.